# c# link objects wrapped on the listbox in WINDOWS PHONE

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, binding, windows-phone

I have this block of code as you can see in the screen print correctly loads the data you want and store the list of objects PopularVideos:

```
item    { Title = Hey Porsche, Url = http://www.unnu.com/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/timthumb.php?src=http://www.unnu.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/019.jpg&amp;h=65&amp;w=275 }    <>f__AnonymousType0<string,string>

item.Title  "Hey Porsche"   string

item.Url    "http://www.unnu.com/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/timthumb.php?src=http://www.unnu.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/019.jpg&amp;h=65&amp;w=275" string
```

Need to load these objects in my list box with binding or has otherwise also can be. But the windows phone does not work with DataSource and DisplayMember.

My XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="listBoxPopular">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Name="imagem" Source="{Binding Path=Url}"/>
                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Titulo}" Tap="HyperlinkButton_Tap"  FontSize="30" Foreground="#FF159DDE" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

My Class is:

```
class PopularVideos
    {
        public PopularVideos() { }
        public PopularVideos(string titulo, string url)
        {
            Titulo = titulo;            
            BitmapImage Img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url));
        }

        public string Titulo { get; set; }

        public Uri Url { get; set; }
    }
```

and my codebehind is:

```
_popVideos = new List<PopularVideos>();
            var data = e.Document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='content']")
               .Descendants("img")
               .Select(img => new
               {
                   Title = img.Attributes["alt"].Value,
                   Url = img.Attributes["src"].Value,
               }).ToList();

            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                PopularVideos pop = new PopularVideos(item.Title, item.Url);
                _popVideos.Add(new PopularVideos(item.Title, item.Url));
            }
            listBoxPopular.ItemsSource = _popVideos;
```

This code works because they are carrying the images and links in the objects, just can not bring up in my list box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have a bindable `ObservableCollection<Item>` (preferrably in a ViewModel).
2. Use the `ListBox.ItemsSource` property to bind to said `ObservableCollection<Item>`. The standard binding rules apply.
3. Each of the items in `ListBox` will be a representation of the items in the core collection that is bound to the control, so bind to its properties the same way you would to anything else.

Comment: Remember, when you're using ObservableCollection when you want to change it, you need to use instance of Dispatcher. (`Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() method`)

Comment: @DenDelimarsky Sorry, but I'm struggling to implement what you said. Must be correct, but as I am beginner I'm not sure how to do what you said.

Comment: @MateuszDembski I do not know how to use it too. Help-me.

Comment: I would recommend starting with an *Intro to databinding* article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80555/Databinding-in-Silverlight-applications

Comment: `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
{
    //Your source code here - code associated with ObservableCollection like add, remove, change, upadate content :)
});`

Comment: @MateuszDembski you tell me to put my foreach inside it?

Comment: Exactly - everything that changes the ObservableCollection have to be fired in GUI thread, and that's what Dispatcher does in this case.

Comment: @MateuszDembski Okay but do not know how to create the ObservableCollection is great information and i am beginner. Is to do this directly with my list?

Comment: ObservableCollection is something like a List, it's a type. You declare it like this (ex): `public ObservableCollection<string> MyCollection;` :) So ObservableCollection you can use instead of List

Comment: Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
            {
                foreach (var item in data)
                {   
                    _popVideos.Add(new PopularVideos(item.Title, item.Url))     listBoxPopular.ItemsSource = _popVideos;           });

Comment: @MateuszDembski See my comments please!

Comment: @Luiz - StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You need to be very specific about what doesn't work and you'll get help if anyone is familiar with the subject.

Comment: @LuizNegrini, you dont need to set ItemSource if you bind to your collectin in xaml: `<ListBox ItemSource="{Binding YourCollection}"` Please remember to set DataContext (if you dont use MVVM patterm, that we recommended you) like this in root element of xaml code: `DataContext = "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"

Comment: @DenDelimarsky My problem is well explained, I showed that I have and just do not know why it does not work.

Comment: @MateuszDembski <ListBox Name="listBoxPopular" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=_popVideos}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Image Name="imagem" Source="{Binding Path=Img}"/>
                                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Img}" Tap="HyperlinkButton_Tap"  FontSize="30" Foreground="#FF159DDE" />... Is this? Now work.... =/

Comment: If it works, that's great ;) You can also remove reduntant Path from Binding - first Property is always Path, so you do not need to write it down.

Answer (score 0):

It's reply to comment:

Ok, please read once again the article that @Den send to you. And please remove `DataContext` `Property` from `ListBox`, add `x:Name="myList"` to `ListBox` and in code-behind: `myList.DataContext = this;` This is not the best solution, but it's easy to understand and firstly you need to understand it :) Best regards.