# ObservableCollection with binding in c# Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone, observablecollection

How to make this list binding with listbox? I can get the data I want, because when I put a breakpoint I see that is being loaded correctly. I heard that they have a ObservableCollection but do not know how to use and then do not bind with the xaml.

```
 private void DownLoadCompleted(object sender, HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted e)
        {
            _popVideos = new List<PopularVideos>();
            var data = e.Document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='content']")
               .Descendants("img")
               .Select(img => new
               {
                   Title = img.Attributes["alt"].Value,
                   Url = img.Attributes["src"].Value,
               }).ToList();

            foreach (var item in data)
            {               
                PopularVideos pop = new PopularVideos(item.Title, item.Url);
                _popVideos.Add(new PopularVideos(item.Title, item.Url));
            }

            listBoxPopular.ItemsSource = _popVideos;
        }
```

My class:

```
class PopularVideos
    {
        public PopularVideos() { }
        public PopularVideos(string titulo, string url)
        {
            Titulo = titulo;            
            BitmapImage Img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url));
        }

        public string Titulo { get; set; }

        public Uri Url { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: first idea - make class PopularVideos => public class PopularVideos

Comment: @jimpanzer Put and kept not working.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478153/c-sharp-link-objects-wrapped-on-the-listbox-in-windows-phone/17479598#17479598), there is a [**great article**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80555/Databinding-in-Silverlight-applications) that you should go through as an intro to data binding.

Comment: An introductory article does not contain everything I need for this to work so I asked again.